# Does jQuery.submit() eventually call the native DOM submit() method?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

Using jQuery, I have recently wondered if these two similar code fragments are equivalent:

```
$('form[name="unique-name"]').submit(); // (call jQuery.submit() on the 
                                        //  collection of 1 form node)
```

vs.

```
$('form[name="unique-name"]')[0].submit(); // (call the native HTMLFormElement.submit()
                                           //  DOM method on the single form in the collection)
```

Both produce the same result in my code (IIRC), but regardless I began to wonder if jQuery is just passing through to the native DOM method, or if it's doing something else entirely. After digging around in the jQuery source, I couldn't find any occurrence of the native DOM submit() ever getting called.

After reading [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and searching I still cannot determine if jQuery is providing a "better" submit() or if they are just passing through to the native DOM submit() across the entire collection. Which is it? Please point me to the source or documentation if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by _better submit_?

Comment: @undefined Better: Improving the submit() concept with features that make sense but didn't make the cut in the W3C spec. Or possibly normalizing the behavior across browser implementations (if quirks exist that I'm not aware of).

Comment: jQuery is open source, why don't you just read the code? But even if it does just call the native submit, it might do something different in the future if necessary for cross-browser consistency. One of the benefits of using a library like jQuery is that it tries to hide browser differences.

Comment: @Barmar I mentioned I have I read the source, but I didn't find anything like a native submit(). I only found a jQuery.event.simulate("submit") call that further suggests DOM submit() is never called. But you make a good point that jQuery's method might have future benefits. My question is really chasing my curiosity about the internals of jQuery rather than planning to not use it.

Comment: jQuery source code can be very difficult to follow just by reading, it's quite convoluted. I'd single-step through a `.submit()` call to see where it goes.

Comment: I should have done that. :) I just traced the code manually start where I got tripped up before, and think I figured it out. See my comment on Paul's answer below. Thanks for the great suggestions, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, jQuery bubbles events up unless you call `event.stopPropagation()`.

My educated guess is this is how it happens for `submit()`:

```
    postDispatch: function( event ) {
        // If form was submitted by the user, bubble the event up the tree
        if ( event._submit_bubble ) {
            delete event._submit_bubble;
            if ( this.parentNode && !event.isTrigger ) {
                jQuery.event.simulate( "submit", this.parentNode, event, true );
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Bubbling: That's a big difference I must have overlooked. I found that code you referenced (thx), and the jQuery.event.simulate("submit") is what really made me question if somehow jQuery is never calling the native DOM submit.

Comment: I just followed jQuery.event.simulate() in the code, and it ultimately calls jQuery.event.trigger(), which calls the DOM default action if it wasn't prevented during the dispatch/bubbling. "try { elem[ type ](); }" The native DOM submit() method eventually gets called there. Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction.